# Sound play sound only once

Tags: java, android

I have a button when clicked it play a sound using sound pool

`mVolume = 6`, `maxVolume = 10`, `minVolume = 0`

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (canPlaySound){
            mSoundPool.play(soundId, (float) mVolume / maxVolume,
                    (float) mVolume / minVolume, 1, 0
                    , 1.0f);
        }
    }
});
```

Debbuging `canPlaySound` is always true but the the sound is played only once when the button is clicked for the first line.

Comment: Are you sure it's played once, or it maybe takes a long time to play before you can click again?

Comment: Noo  its a beep sound, very short @Stefan